# How to auto shrink and magnify view using AutoLayout when rotate

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

For the size of a view, I can use x:x ratio to superview. When superview shrink, the subView will auto resize.

[image]
[image]

In picture two, superView size changed.

My question is how to handle horizontal and vertical space constraint to "auto recalculate constraint"? I do can control drag all these constraints into a NSArray, and in LayoutSubView, check the rotation (by self.view.width > xxx), and set every new value (by divide or multiply a ratio) for all of them. However, this method is really ugly. Is there a better way to make all size and constraints auto resize when the superView changes? Such as in iPad, all view can auto resize in ratio 768/1024.